# In Chrome dev tools is it possible to decode the binary response with content type application/protobuf over HTTP

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have an endpoint called over HTTP that responds with application/protobuf content type data but the content is in binary I believe. When looking at it on Chrome is it possible to decode it somehow?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that a ArrayBuffer?

Comment: I don't know about inside Chrome, but if you can save the payload as a file or hex/base-64 and it is protobuf: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode

Comment: @marc-gravell I think your comment should be the answer. Perhaps with the additional information that, this isn't possible in Chrome by default. This is, in part, because on-the-wire (binary) protobuf data isn't self-describing and you need either the `.proto` (schema), a descriptor file or your clever tool to uncover the original message.

Comment: Did you find how to do this?
@MarcGravell I don't understand what I should paste on your tool. I tried it today with the output of the chrome network dev tool (similar to the screenshot above) and got errors about not being a valid input.

Comment: @user313551 then it probably isn't valid protobuf data?